# Rails data not being saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following code snippets:

```
oldroompaxinfo = Roompaxinfo.find(:all, :conditions =>["bkgitem_id = ?",bkgitemid])

.... some code to identify which passenger ids have changed

roompaxinfo = Roompaxinfo.find(:first, :conditions => ["bkgitem_id = ? and roomno = ?  and pax_id = ?", bkgitemid, roomno, oldpaxid])

roompaxinfo.pax_id = newpaxid
roompaxinfo.save

..... some code to send the changes to a remote service.

#If errors occur during send I want to re-instate the old info 
if retcode.index('Error') != nil
   oldroompaxinfo.each do |rp|
       rp.save
   end
end
```

And the problem is that that last bit of code is NOT  saving the old data back.  In case somebody thinks  it is not being executed because of the condition check then I have  already proven that it does by outputting some stuff in flash.  I've also tried rp.save! but that didn't help either.

I'm using MySQL with Ruby 1.8 and Rails 2.3.8

Comment: What does the development.log say? Does it show the SQL queries being executed?

Comment: @Dogbert the log wasn't showing any attempts to save. Dylan's answer was the reason.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hit your loop, Rails doesn't think that `rp` is "dirty", so doing a save doesn't actually touch the database. Rails will only issue an `update` statement if there are changed attributes.

You may need to save the old parameters you want (just `pax_id`?), reload the `rp` record, and then try saving:

```
oldroompaxinfo.each do |rp|
  pax_id = rp.pax_id
  rp.reload
  rp.update_attributes(:pax_id => pax_id)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and that does work. However some one on another forum suggested that I put the whole thing under a transaction and  roll back if the submit to the service fails which seems like a more logical way of doing this.